# Select option in Laravel vs search

Tags: laravel, search, html-select

it is in laravel. I would like to search and then select the data in a mysql table. currently im using a select option drop down menu. the list will eventually be unreasonably to long to use. so i would like to type the words and it will then give me the options. in my database table i have the team name email and address and zip code.

```
    <div id="team_model" class="modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <form method="post" action="{{url("athlete/request_for_team_sibling")}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="modal-body">

                <input type="hidden" name="id" id="teamuserid"  value=''>

                <select class="form-control form-control-sm teamselect" id="teamselect" required name="team_id">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Select Team</option>
                    @foreach($teams as $team)
                        <option value="{{$team->id}}">{{$team->name}}&nbsp;{{$team->address}}&nbsp;{{$team->city}}&nbsp;{{$team->state}}&nbsp;{{$team->zipcode}}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="submit"  class="btn btn-primary saveteam">Save</button>
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal" value="Close">
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: the feature you want is called autocomplete. it will involve Ajax to retrieve data from your server.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $Teams = Team::where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $request['team_id'] . '%')
      ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', '%' . $request['team_id']  . '%')
      ->orWhere('address', 'LIKE', '%' . $request['team_id']  . '%')
      ->orWhere('zipcode', 'LIKE', '%' . $request['team_id']  . '%')
      ->get();
```

Comment: What line I the code do I place your code.

Comment: that should be inside your controller. when you render your view.

this might help  https://www.tutsmake.com/laravel-where-like-query-example/